# Ionic 3 App issue accessing location service

Tags: ionic3, cordova-plugins, android-location

I have developed an app using ionic 3.
ionic info of my app is given below.

cli packages:

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.9.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.9.2
```

global packages:

```
Cordova CLI : 7.1.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.0
Cordova Platforms  : none
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
Node              : v8.12.0
npm               : 6.4.1
OS                : Windows 10
```

I'm using location access in order fetch the user current location,but facing some weird issues while testing the app on device using android-debug.apk.

[location access permission pop-up,which is called at the beginning of the application.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Jupb.png)

[After clicking allow, still could not access location.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHa5C.png)

[Able to access location after resuming or restating the application.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CnqHT.png)

In order to fetch location I'm using [cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation](https://github.com/mauron85/cordova-plugin-background-geolocation) and calling the same service after Platform().ready(),but when app goes in the background again the location service gets disabled/inaccessible so my background service is also getting fail.

Your prompt response is highly appreciable.

Comment: how are you requesting the location in your code  ?

Comment: I'm using "cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation" plugin for geo- location.

Comment: I have created a service which is getting called after platform.ready().